# How to derive weights for bucketized_column in tf.estimator.LinearRegressor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am studying Google Crash ML cause.
I have trouble in chapter “Feature Cross”.

https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/feature-crosses/programming-exercise

I tried to get the weight of cross feature from `linear_regressor`.

```
# here I change _ to linear_model 
linear_model = train_model(
               learning_rate=1.0,
               steps=500,
               batch_size=100,
               feature_columns=construct_feature_columns(),
               training_examples=training_examples,
               training_targets=training_targets,
               validation_examples=validation_examples,
               validation_targets=validation_targets)

Weight_bucketized_longitude= linear_model.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/bucketized_longitude/weights')   
print(Weight_bucketized_longitude)
```

However, I got error message as below:

Error Message:

> NotFoundError: Key linear/linear_model/bucketized_longitude/weights
>   not found in checkpoint

It looks like the path is wrong.
The path works for `numeric_column`, but it doesn’t for `bucketized_column`.

Could you help to indicate the correct path?
Thanks.

#### #

I tried Geeocode's method.
However, I still got error message.

```
Weight_bucketized_longitude= linear_model.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/bucketized_longitude/weights')
```

> AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 Weight_bucketized_longitude= >linear_model.get_variable_value(["linear", "linear_model", >"bucketized_longitude", "weights"])
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist->packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.pyc in >get_variable_value(self, name)
>      252     _check_checkpoint_available(self.model_dir)
>      253     with context.graph_mode():
>   --> 254       return training.load_variable(self.model_dir, name)
>      255 
>      256   def get_variable_names(self):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist->packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.pyc in >load_variable(ckpt_dir_or_file, name)
>       77   """
>       78   # TODO(b/29227106): Fix this in the right place and remove >this.
>   ---> 79   if name.endswith(":0"):
>       80     name = name[:-2]
>       81   reader = load_checkpoint(ckpt_dir_or_file)
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `linear_model.get_variable_value()` have to pass a list of string with variables' name. From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor):

> **get_variable_value**
>
> `get_variable_value(name)`
>
> Returns value of the variable given by name.
>
> Args: name: **string or a list of string, name of the tensor**. Returns:
>   Numpy array - value of the tensor.
>
> Raises: ValueError: If the Estimator has not produced a checkpoint
>   yet.

Thus your code should changes as follow:

```
Weight_bucketized_longitude= linear_model.get_variable_value(["linear", "linear_model", "bucketized_longitude", "weights"])
```

Comment: Hi Geeocode, Thanks for help. I tried your code, but I still got error message. I update the result on my post. Thanks!

Comment: @Sean Hi Sean, Now I took a deeper look to your problem. Actually the doc i linked is another version of this method, so you have to use variable string. But to update my answer and give you a solution to your problem I need further details. Why you expect that there is a variable that you wanted to get in the checkpoint? Why you try to get it in path way like /path/to/some/variable? You mentioned "The path works for numeric_column" but actually what was the code snippet what worked?

Comment: @Sean Note: if you need get answer to your question, please don't late with responses and answer as much as 1 nearly month.

Comment: I Hi Geeocode, Thanks for update. I am sorry to let you feel I don't take your response serious. That's my fault, and I have no excuse. I read your answer again. I find I shall read the document as you provide in your comment before asking. From the  documentation, I find I can use get_variable_names() to get the paths of all features. Thanks for help. I deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sean Hi Sean, It's OK, I was happy to help you.